# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is extremly slow on mac M1

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, apple-m1

I'm using Mac Air M1 and trying to run IntelliJ Ultimate.

I've read some issues on JetBrains YouTrack and it seems that a lot of people are pretty satisfied with their experience. So, I think something is wrong with my environment and I can't find out what

**Steps I've done:**

1. Rebooted my Mac
2. Invalidated Caches & Restarted IDE
3. Reinstalled IntelliJ
4. Deleted "Caches" and "Application Support/JetBrains" directories and then reinstalled IDE
5. Checked if I'm using a default Java Runtime version
6. Checked if I'm using Intel version of IDE
7. Disabled Antialiasing
8. Closed "heavy" apps like Google Chrome
9. Installed Atom Material Icons plugin
10. Downloaded prebuilt shared indexes
11. Modified .vmoptions and added

```
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
-Dsun.java2d.opengl.fbobject=false
```

12. Disabled Smooth scrolling
13. I'm not using external display, mac is connected to power outlet

**Here is my environment:**

IntelliJ:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5080.210, built on April 12, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1024M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.mallowigi (64.0.0)
    Dart (221.5588)
    io.flutter (66.0.4)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.20-release-285-IJ5080.210
```

Mac:

```
Model Name: MacBook Air
Chip: Apple M1
Total Number of Cores: 8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
Memory: 8 GB
OS: macOS Monterey Version 12.1
```

**Related YouTrack topics**

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268203
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-3237
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2732

**UPDATE #1:**
Moved issue to JetBrains YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293523/IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate-is-extremly-slow-on-mac-M1

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the CPU snapshot and the logs, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085.

Comment: Seems 2022.1 has major performance issues on all platforms. Try an older version or 2022.1.1 Preview

Answer (score 9):

You can see the memory usage of your application and increase it accordingly if required. In my case, it was slow because of low memory.

1. Enable the memory indicator by checking it (View -> Appearance -> Status Bar Widgets -> Memory Indicator). With this, now you can see memory usage details in the bottom right corner of your Intellij IDE.
2. Increase the memory if it's exhausted more than 80% of available memory by following: Click on Help -> Change Memory Settings -> <>)

[image: Memory Settings]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with same MBA.

I changed the runtime to OpenJDK 18 and now it is totally smooth :)
Help -> Find action -> Choose boot runtime for the IDE

I experimented with a few other JDKs, maybe Azul was the fastest.
Also, I have updated Xmx:
Help -> Edit Custom VM Options and updated to 2048m

To me, seems like the issue is resolved now or at least way better.

Comment: My Rider was on the connecting to host for a long time and then sync project as well. Followed your suggestion but instead of selecting OpenJDK I just clicked on the select default runtime and the perf issues seem to have gone away. From around 10m to load a single project back to 10~20 seconds

Comment: On OSX apple silicon i switches to openjdk and my indexing time went from ~9min to ~1min

Answer (score 2):

My building time were very slow compared to my colleagues.

After some investigation I realised I was using a java that was optimised for Intel.

You can easily find out by looking at the **Kind** column in Activity Monitor

*(If you don't see java running just start a build from intellji)*

[image]

I realised that you need a java build for **aarch64**

Just go to you project settings and download a java version with aarch64 as shown below.

[image]

Then select the correct SDK version in Project Settings > Project & Modules.

My build time are now twice faster, bingo!

I hope that can help a few of you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/), which runs on JBR 17 with [Metal framework](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-745/Improve-java2d-rendering-performance-on-macOS-by-using-Metal-fra).

Answer (score 0):

I download the M1 version for intellij ultimate and I have a incredible improve in performance.
BTW: I have a macbook pro 13' with 16gb ram and 1TB ssd

intellij environment

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Licensed to ********************
Subscription is active until ********.
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1024M
Cores: 8
Registry:
*************

Non-Bundled Plugins:
monokai-pro (1.8.1)
com.vincentp.gruvbox-theme (0.5.4)
com.intellij.plugins.macoskeymap (221.5591.19)
com.github.rmatafonov.cucumber-scenarios-indexer (1.1.0)
com.github.chencn.yamlandprops (1.0.5)
net.lagerwey.cucumber-kotlin (2022.1.0)
dev.eltonsandre.intellij.spring.assistant.plugin (1.5.2)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.21-release-337-IJ5591.52

Answer (score 0):

From dive deep into community i found this reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/q05b29/intellij_idea_for_m1_macbook/ its basicly tells you to install Rosetta2, also battery-consuming, I think it just best if  you use mac mini setup(not a macos user, but wish to anw)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem on Apple M2 Pro with Ultimate version.
Turning on [Displays have separate Spaces](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-3237/Editing-and-scrolling-is-slow-on-M1-version#focus=Comments-27-6855594.0-0) reduce the lagging for me.